# @import "bootstrap/less/tables.less"; no effect when importing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

as soon as I use another less file like "bootstrap/less/tables.less" its not working anymore(on the client side in fire bug the less -file has no content at all), but when I use "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less" everthing is fine (intelli sense is working on both files).
The files are from "Bootstrap.Less". VS doesnt show me an error.

Background information for my project:
Important NuGet Pakages:

- Bootstrap (v 3.0.0 ) -> imported in the master page
- Bootstrap.Less (v 2.3.2 ) ->these files I use for impor in
  "Site.less")
- dotless (v 1.4.0.0)
- html5shiv (v 0.1.0.8)
- Modernizr (v 2.6.2) -> imported in the master page
- Respond JS (v 1.2.0)

Visual Studio 2013

- MVC5

My aim is only to use the less files I really need like "bottons.less" or "tables.less", can you please help me ?

Comment: mmh, what could have gone wrong ... ?

Comment: Pleae provide a working example, in order to allow us investigate. Thank you.